# How to format negative numbers with parenthesis with OpenXLSX in R

Tags: r, openxlsx

I'm using R to process some data and then OpenXLSX to output to an .xlsx file. I'd like negative numbers to be in accounting format, so in parenthesis (-100 is (100)), but without the $ or decimals.

If I add the parenthesis during my data processing phase before the OpenXLSX section, that turns it into a character vector, which does not work, I need it to export as a number type. I've also tried

```
num <- createStyle(numFmt = "ACCOUNTING")
addStyle(wb, 1, style = num, rows = 4:53, cols = 3:6, gridExpand = T, stack = T)
```

which does add the parenthesis but also adds a dollar sign and two decimals, which I do not want.

Comment: cant you just use regular synthax for negative numbers (`-100`), and adjust the methods for displaying the values inside excel? I am not sure, but I believe whether excel shows values as () or - is more of a display option, and not how the values are encoded.

Comment: While I technically could, that wouldn't really accomplish what I want since I want the excel output to already be completely formatted and not need any manual intervention

Comment: A way out might be to format the data.frame in R the way you want it to be, then to export it as text but I haven't tested this idea.

Comment: @Laura, I suspect the  dollar sign and the decimals are governed by the excel default format. On the R side unfortunately, I could not find any solution. I might be worth it to raise the issue on the repository [here](https://github.com/ycphs/openxlsx/issues)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found a way to make this work without using formal styling (creating a workbook and worksheet, assigning specific styles to specific rows and columns).

Here's a working example.

I've added some comments to explain the arguments in `addStyle`. If that doesn't help or you have any questions, let me know.

```
library(openxlsx)

wb <- createWorkbook()               # create structure/workbook
addWorksheet(wb, "formatting")       # create sheet and name it
                                     # create data to add to workbook
df1 <- data.frame(values1 = -10:10, values2 = 10:-10, letters = LETTERS[1:21])

writeData(wb, "formatting", df1)     # add data to sheet "formatting"

                                     # add styling
# wb, sheet 1, () for negs, first 2 cols, 100 rows
addStyle(wb, 1, style = createStyle(numFmt = '#,##0.00_);(#,##0.00)'), 
         cols = 1:2, rows = 2:100, gridExpand = T)
saveWorkbook(wb, "newSpreadsheet.xlsx", overwrite = T) # save formatted wb
```